# geoserver nginx proxy_pass not working well

Tags: nginx, proxypass

i have this config to access geoserver :

```
location /geoserver {
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

every this work fine when i access geoserver webpage but nginx not handle requests like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&access_token=4r3irW5W3DboGs…7091932%2C-5009377.085697312%2C-10018754.17139462%2C-9.313225746154785e-10
```

this error appear in console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&access_token=4r3irW5W3DboGs…7091932%2C-5009377.085697312%2C-10018754.17139462%2C-9.313225746154785e-10 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i want to nginx to replace `http://localhost:8080` with `IP`

**Update**

i removed slash but some requests not working well

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&TILED=true&VERSION=1.1.1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i copied the url in browser and replaced `localhost:8080` with IP it works!!!

***full configrations  :***

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
    }

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name XX.XX.XX.XX;
    charset     utf-8;

    #Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 1024M;   # adjust to tast

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    location /geoserver {
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_redirect off;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is anything running on `localhost:8080` on the machine running nginx?

Comment: yes geoserver is running on localhost:8080

Comment: Are you saying that the browser is being redirected to `localhost:8080`?

Comment: @RichardSmith no this is ajax request

Comment: Could you please update your question to mention this is for ajax? Could you also check and mention whether or not _all_ URLs shown by/related to geoserver use localhost instead of the domain configured in nginx? A full example of the kind of request you are making, and what is breaking, would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have a prefix location and `prox_pass` statement with a URI. Where you need `nginx` to perform an aliasing function, the `location` value and the `proxy_pass` URI should either both end with a `/` or neither end with a `/` or the mapped URI will be malformed.

```
location /geoserver {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

However, in your case, you are mapping `/geoserver` to `/geoserver` which is pointless, so the non-URI version of `proxy_pass` will suffice and will be more efficient:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
```

Comment: I have updated  the question